# Manual for new version devise 1.5 and omniauth 1.0.0 facebook with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, mongoid, omniauth

I am following the new manual for install new version omniauth 1.0.0 with new version devise in

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

But this manual its for Mysql I think. Im working with **Mongoid.**

I have try update the query for the mongoid syntax:

In **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

if **@user.persisted?** I have changed by **if @user.create**

In the model **user.rb**

I have change **if user = User.find_by_email(data.email)** by **if user = User.where(email: (data.email))**

The problem is that in callback when the user come back from facebook I get the next error:

```
Could not find a valid mapping for #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:email=>"emailusercomebackfacebook"},
  options:  {},
  class:    User,
  embedded: false>
```

Any idea? Where can I get a guide or manual for new devise and omniauth for Mongoid?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to put a map after the where, and see what it returns. (`User.where(email: (data.email)).map`).

Comment: I get the next message in controller: **undefined method save for #<Enumerator:0xbfc5390>** If I put `@user.save` or `@user.create` in the conditional from controller. If I put `if @user` alone I get: `RuntimeError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
Could not find a valid mapping for #<Enumerator: #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:email=>"emailusercomebackfacebook"},
  options:  {},
  class:    User,
  embedded: false>
:map>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to do two changes:

1) `User.find_by_email(data.email)` needs to be `User.where(:email => data.email).first`

2) `User.create!(:email => data.email, :encrypted_password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])` needs to be `User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20], :name => "Dummy Name")`

Notice I am using "Dummy Name" above, you should get the name from facebook data instead.

Comment: Thanks now working fine. For working put :name => "data.name" and working fine :D Problem its fixed. Thank you very much Jose for fix this problem with the new gem :D. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the first element and see if it is the instance you want. Mongoid seems to be returning a Enumerable with the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have add the next query to model:

```
if user = (User.where(email:(data.email)).map.first)
```

Now the error is in the model:

```
Mongoid::Errors::Validations in 

Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

Validation failed - Password can't be blank, Name can't be blank.

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:21:in 'find_for_facebook_oauth'
app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in 'facebook'
```

With the new query the script go to **else** in the **if** sentence

The line that produce the error in the else is:

```
else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    User.create!(:email => data.email, :encrypted_password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
```

To try create the user with stub password